# Find 93 using first 4 prime numbers

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

Using operators plus (+), minus (-), multiplication (x) and division (/), power function/exponentiation (^) and as many brackets as you want, can you find

> A formula which uses 2,3,5,7 to make 93?

Comment: I would be able to do it with *two* $2$s; i.e., $5^3-2^{7-2}=93$. (The same goes for two $5$s since $7-2=5$.) Also, including concatenation, I could create another formula with two $2$s: $57+(2\times 3)^2$, and another: $75+(2\times 3^2)$, and yet another: $23 + (2\times 5\times 7)$, and even another: $73 + (5\times 2^2)$.

Comment: I finally was able to make one, but it uses a $0$. $$7^3-250=93.$$ That's the best I can do without using @Glorfindel 's answer.

Comment: @user477343  Glorfindel's answer is unique :)

Comment: Indeed... but is there a way to prove that his answer is the *only* one that satisfies the puzzle?

Comment: @user477343 yes coding.

Comment: Well there seem to be many formulae when you have the opportunity of using two $2$s, oddly enough. Another one: $3^{2^2}+5+7=93$ :)

Comment: @user477343 mostly if you have 5 numbers, you will get 93 easily.

Comment: @user477343 $2-(2-3\cdot5)\cdot7$ without power.  $2+(2^3+5)\cdot7$, $2+(2\cdot5+3)\cdot7$, $(2\cdot2\cdot5+73)$, $2^2\cdot5+73$, $22\cdot(7-3)+5$ etc..

Comment: Yes. Two $7$s results in $((5^2\times (7-3))-7$. I am now pretty convinced that the answer below is the only solution. Great puzzle, though! :D ..... **Edit:** How did you find the equations so quickly? Was that done via coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are we allowed to

> concatenate numbers?

If so,

> $2^7 - 35 = 93$ works.

Comment: no restriction for concatenation is defined, so you can :) good finding!

Comment: Concatenation strictly speaking is an operation, and isn’t listed as one.

Comment: @NeilW sure, hence my question if it was allowed. I've tried to brute force a solution without concatenation later, but that wasn't successful.